# IdentityServer token authorization in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver3

Hoping someone can help with this.

I have an IdentityServer3 setup that we're using scope authorization with in existing projects.

We've just created an API application that is on .NET Core and running into some issues with this and how to get it to work as expected.

This API resource is effectively a middleman. A token is requested on the client which then in turn calls the API. Quite a standard model.

We're expecting to use Authorization to handle 2 cases: 
1. The token is valid
2. The token is valid for the specified scope of the API resource ([Authorize(Scope="Scope1")] for instance)

However it doesn't look like the API is hooking into the IS3 instance at all.

The code looks as follows:

**Startup**

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://identityserver3server";
                //options.ApiSecret = "";
                options.ApiName = "ApiName";
                options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;
            });
```

options.ApiName - this seems to be scope related from my reading but at this level we wouldn't want to specify requirements in scope at this level instead we would want to do that in the controller. 
options.ApiSecret - Is this even required?

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Scope1", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("Scope1", "")));
        });
```

**ScopeRequirement**

```
 public class HasScopeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Scope { get; }

    public HasScopeRequirement(string scope, string issuer)
    {
        Scope = scope ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scope));
    }
}

public class HasScopeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasScopeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasScopeRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "scope"))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        var scopes = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "scope").Value.Split(' ');

        if (scopes.Any(s => s == requirement.Scope))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

From here the idea is we can do the following:

**Controller**

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize("Scope1")]
public class PingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("ping")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Ping()
    {
        return Ok("Ping pong");
    }
}
```

Comment: A little addition: `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();`